# pandas comparing data frame slices

Tags: python, loops, numpy, pandas

I am working with two data frames in pandas (df_A has ~6500 rows and df_B  ~7.5 million) and have come to a point where I can't think of a way to avoid iterating through rows.

this is what df_A looks like:

```
bidders  other_col1   other_col2
'abcd'      2             3
'efgh'      123           4
```

this is what df_B looks like:

```
bidders    time   other_col3
'abcd'     23456       67
'abcd'     23456       43
'jklm'     7896       190
'jklm'     7896       456
```

Basically I need to compare each unique bidder in df_A to bidders in df_B. Then I need to find all the unique timestamps where the bidder ids match, and for those unique timestamps, i need to iterate through df_B to find the number of times a bidder in df_B appears for the same timestamp

This is what my script would look like:

```
simul_count = 0:

for bidder in df_A['bidders']:

   loc = (df_B['bidders'] == bidder)
   unique_times = pd.unique(df_B.loc[loc, 'time'])

   for time in unique_times:

      loc1 = (df_B['bidders'] == bidder) & (df_B['time'] == time)

      if len(df_B.loc1[loc1, 'bidders']) > 1:
          simul_count += 1
```

So if we ran through the above code, simul_count = 1 for the sample data I provided since Bidder 'abcd' made 2 bids at the same time. I know this operation will take an eternity in python as is. Using numpy functions and arrays could provide a small boost I suppose; but is there a much faster way?

EDIT: Just to be clear, the script should output the unique bidder id, the number of times it made simultaneous bids, and the timestamp when the simultaneous bid was made. The timestamp would make checking suggestions much easier :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you want?:

```
bidder_counts = pd.merge(df_A,df_B).groupby(['bidders', 'time']).count()
bidder_counts[bidder_counts.other_col1 > 1].other_col1

bidders  time 
'abcd'   23456    2
Name: other_col1, dtype: int64
```

**(Edited to explain my answer in more detail):**
The Pandas merge is like a SQL INNER JOIN, where by default it will join on any common columns; in this case the column 'bidder':

```
pd.merge(df_A,df_B)
  bidders  other_col1  other_col2   time  other_col3
0  'abcd'           2           3  23456          67
1  'abcd'           2           3  23456          43
```

`groupby` is the same as GROUP BY in SQL; basically it will loop through distinct values of the column that you pass it, and then you can perform whatever aggregate function you want on each group. Here we are just doing count, but you could do sum or something else if you wanted.

```
pd.merge(df_A,df_B).groupby('time').count()

       bidders  other_col1  other_col2  other_col3
time                                              
23456        2           2           2           2
```

Finally I'm filtering based on counts>2 and then returning the length of the result; I had to specify a column to filter on so I chose bidders because I thought it makes more semantic sense: `bidder_counts[bidder_counts.bidders > 1]`; however notice that all the counts are the same, so I could have also done `bidder_counts[bidder_counts.other_col1 > 1]`

Comment: I am afraid I don't entirely understand what your suggestion does. Would you mind walking me through it?

Comment: Ok so I tried your suggestion, but I just get a cumulative count. The example I gave above is a very very small chunk of the data. I need a count of bidders that bids at the same time AND their bidder_id

Comment: OK I've edited my answer to include bidder in the groupby, this isn't what you asked in the question though, in your example code, you just have `simul_count` as a single number, not a per-bidder count.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you want to count the number of times a bidder appeared for the same timestamp, and these bidders need to be present in `df_A`. Here, `a`and `b` are your `df_A` and `df_B` respectively.

```
In [35]: a
Out[35]: 
  bidders  other_col1  other_col2
0  'abcd'           2           3
1  'efgh'         123           4
```

Added a `count` column to `b`:

```
In [36]: b
Out[36]: 
  bidders   time  other_col3  count
0  'abcd'  23456          67      1
1  'abcd'  23456          43      1
2  'jklm'   7896         190      1
3  'jklm'   7896         456      1

appearances = b.groupby(['bidders','time']).sum()['count'].reset_index()

In [38]: appearances
Out[38]: 
  bidders   time  count
0  'abcd'  23456      2
1  'jklm'   7896      2

In [39]: a.merge(appearances, how='right').drop(['other_col1','other_col2'], axis=1)
Out[39]: 
  bidders   time  count
0  'abcd'  23456      2
1  'jklm'   7896      2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it

First get unique bidders from `df_A`

```
In [32]: bidders=df_A['bidders'].unique()

In [33]: bidders
Out[33]: array(["'abcd'", "'efgh'"], dtype=object)
```

Then extract data of selected bidders`df_B['bidders'].isin(bidders)`, groupby on `bidders` and count unique values of `time`

```
In [34]: df_B[df_B['bidders'].isin(bidders)].groupby('bidders')['time'].nunique()
Out[34]:
bidders
'abcd'     1
Name: time, dtype: int64
```

If you want to get bidder IDs for each timestamp then, groupby `time`, get the unique list of bidders-ids via `x['bidders'].unique()` in `apply()`

```
In [35]: (df_B[df_B['bidders'].isin(bidders)]
              .groupby('time')
              .apply(lambda x: x['bidders'].unique()))
Out[35]:
time
23456    ['abcd']
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: (DF_B_1) 
- From B,Get all distinct bifferent,time and count 
Step 2: (DF_B_2) 
Filter records ONLY where count>1
(Those are potential candidate)

Step 3: 
Merge DF_B_2 with DF_A using bidder column and how=inner. This will filter out bidders not in DF_A

```
pseudo code:

DF_B_1 = df_B.groupBy(["bidders","time"]).count.sum()
DF_B_2 = DF_B_1[count>1]
res = merge(left=DF_B_2,right=df_A,how=inner)
```